# Can't restore backup from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2005 or 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get a backup from SQL Server 2008 R2 restored to SQL Server 2008, but when we try to do the restore we get this:

*The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1092. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.2531. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.*

I can use the script wizard to generate a script, but that takes over an hour to run.  I also tried just exporting the data from server to server, but it had issues with the primary keys/identity columns.  I will be running into this issue with several other clients so any help you could offer about how to get around this would be great.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/62070/can-i-restore-a-sql-2008-database-to-a-sql-2005-server/62072#62072 as well as the link in the comment to my answer.  Scripting is pretty much it.  RedGate's SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare but be able to get you farther, though.

Comment: I just ran into this.  Microsoft should be ashamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much stuck with scripting. Databases travel up the chain easily but you can't go back a version in the same way.

Comment: Yep, it looks like scripting is the only way.  I was hoping to only have to have one SQL Server running, but it looks like I'll have to run side by side versions.